# Event - catch only for qtablewidget; pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

I would like to change behavior of **Key_C** keypressevent or create custom keypressevent handler only for **QTableWidget**, also cause all form created in QtDesigner I want to implement this via code in tablemain.py. In addition, I found that according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747304/event-catch-only-qt-key-delete) I need to promote my **QTableWidget** in QtDesigner, but I don't know how to perform this action correctly.
So, one more time main goal is to:

1. Handle **Key_C** keyPressEvent only for **QTableWidget** which was imported from QtDesigner form, and only when we focused on it copy selected cells into clipboard. *table.ui*, *table.py*, *tablemain.py* all files PSB:

[image: Illustration of the desired state:]

table.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>749</width>
    <height>519</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>611</width>
      <height>371</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="alternatingRowColors">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="gridStyle">
     <enum>Qt::DotLine</enum>
    </property>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1st column</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2nd column</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3rd column</string>
     </property>
    </column>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>749</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

table.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'table.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(749, 519)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 611, 371))
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 749, 19))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1st column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2nd column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3rd column"))
```

tablemain.py

```
import sys
import os
import io
import time
from table import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.clipboard = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard
        self.ui.tableWidget.keyPressEvent = self.tableWidgetSentKeyPressEvent


    def tableWidgetSentKeyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_C:
            self.copy()
        return QtWidgets.QTableWidget.keyPressEvent(self.ui.tableWidget, event)

    # def keyPressEvent(self, e):

    #     """
    #     Captures keypresses to handle copy, cut, and paste.

    #     Arguments:
    #     e   --  a QKeyEvent.
    #     """

        # if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete:
        #     self._clear()
        #     e.ignore()
        # elif e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and e.key() == \
        #     QtCore.Qt.Key_X:
        #     self.cut()
        #     e.ignore()
        # elif e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and e.key() == \
        #     QtCore.Qt.Key_C:
        #     self.copy()
        #     e.ignore()
        # elif e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and e.key() == \
        #     QtCore.Qt.Key_V:
        #     self.paste()
        #     e.ignore()
        # else:
        #     QtWidgets.QTableWidget.keyPressEvent(self, e)

    def copy(self):

        """Copies data from the table into the clipboard."""

        _range =  self.ui.tableWidget.selectedRanges()[0]
        rows = []
        for row in range(_range.topRow(), _range.bottomRow()+1):
            columns = []
            for column in range(_range.leftColumn(), _range.rightColumn()+1):
                item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, column)
                if item != None:
                    value = str(item.text())
                else:
                    value = u''
                columns.append(value)
            rows.append(u'\t'.join(columns))
        selection = u'\n'.join(rows)
        self.clipboard().setText(selection)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40469607/984421

Comment: @ekhumoro, Thank you very much! everything works as expected.